# Dividing Facebook fullname and save as two arrays

Tags: facebook, registration

I already use a MySQL database and want to combine with Facebook Connect. I did a fb:registration plugin and there I can get only the full name. How can I divide it into first name and surname and save those as two arrays?

Comment: What language are you passing it through? PHP: `$name_arr = explode(' ',$name); $first = $name_arr[0]; $last = $name_arr[1];`

Comment: i wrote in php-sdk3.0 and u can find the total code on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574082/storing-facebook-data-to-mysql

Comment: You realize, of course, that in some cultures the surname comes first?

Comment: And that sometimes there's a middle_name ? :/
Hard to find which part of the string will correspond to first_name, middle_name, and last_name this way :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps :)

```
$name_arr = explode(' ',$name,2);
$first = $name_arr[0];
$last = isset($name_arr[1])?$name_arr[1]:'';
```

The first and last name are separated by the first space ' '.

---

Now excluding middle name :D

```
$name_arr = explode(' ',$name,3);
$first = $name_arr[0];
$last = isset($name_arr[1])?(isset($name_arr[2])?$name_arr[2]:$name_arr[1]):'';
```

Comment: thanks for your help i almost only save people coming from germany and europe but i already dont know how to insert this in mysql_query

Comment: just have a look at my earlier posts here, there u can find the total code i use for the moment

Answer (score 1):

You better use Graph API or FQL to get this info for your users if you want to be sure to get the correct first and last name in places...

With Graph API you can request info for multiple users like this:

```
GET http://graph.facebook.com/?ids={uid_1},{uid_2},{uid_n}&fields=first_name,last_name
```

There is some limits for number of users you can request info for (I'm not sure on the numbers, but 50 users works ok) and on URL length (which can be worked around issuing POST request and specifying `method` parameter equal to `get` to Graph API